# Tracking stop playing Audio event?

Tags: events, audio, analytics

I am tracking events in Analytics, but I have a question with audio tag.
I can track when the audio tag is played, but I don't know how to track how long the audio track has been played.
Did the user listen it all ?
Or how long did he listened it ?
Curently I used onclick=" ga('send', 'event', 'Audio', 'play', 'Lecture');"
But what will it be to know how long it has been listened to?
thanks for your help !

Comment: up. No idea at all ?

Comment: up up ? Thanks !